# Is it possible to change your name while applying for a Green Card in the US?

Tags: immigration, greencard, names, international-law

Is it possible to get a Green Card with a different name of your current name? Or change it as soon as getting the Green Card?

I am on F-1 student visa in the US and want to apply for an EB-2/NIW/Green Card, but I'd like to also pick a new name and family name for myself.

Answer (score 1):

> Or change it as soon as getting the Green Card?

Yes, see https://berardiimmigrationlaw.com/legally-change-name/:

> Federal law does allow permanent residents to change their names. For those with permanent resident status who would like to do so, here’s what you’ll need to do. First, follow the legal name change process required by your state.
>
> After this is done, U.S. Citizen and Immigration Services recommends that you replace your green card with one that has your new name. The process begins with filling out USCIS Form I-90: Application to Replace Permanent Resident Card. Supporting documents and a fee will be required. If approved, you will be sent a new green card. If USCIS wants more information, you may need to go to a USCIS office for an interview or provide the original copy of the legal document confirming your name change.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to receive a green card with a name other than your actual official name.

Once you're a permanent resident in the US, you can follow the same process for name change as everyone else (usually involves State court signing off on a name change petition), and then applying for a green card replacement due to the name change. You should also check with your country of citizenship, though, since their requirements may differ and may require you to use that country's process for name change.

If you're going through a naturalization in the US, you *can* ask for a name change as part of the process. In that case, your naturalization ceremony will be held in front of a Federal judge who'd also sign off on the name change as part of the ceremony and you'll get your naturalization certificate with the new name (this may delay the process a bit though, since not every naturalization ceremony is scheduled to be in front of a Federal judge).

Comment: So you mean also for the second case I must follow the state court procedure? No time difference either if I do it before or at the time of citizenship process?

Comment: @GoodMan as a stand-alone process you'll do it based on the State law through the State courts. As part of the naturalization process you'll go through the Federal process and Federal court (the judge administering the oath for you). Not sure I understand the question about time difference - what difference are you asking about?

Comment: I want to know which one is faster? I mean if I do right it after I get my green card it'll be done sooner(the process is shorter/simpler) or if I go through it through the naturalization process?

Comment: @GoodMan naturalization process will start only 3-5 years after you get your green card. So if it is a burning issue clearly you don't want to wait this long. Check at your local courthouse about the specific process and timelines.